# Override sonar projectKey when using maven

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I want to group 25 modules under a single project key so I can get a consolidated view of code duplication.  However the sonar maven plugin uses the `<groupId>:<artifactId>` so each project is separate.

I've tried overriding the `sonar.projectKey` but the maven plugin doesn't consider it.

Is there a way of grouping modules together under a single name so that you can have an aggregate view?
Or is there some other in the sonarqube server to get that aggregate view?

Comment: Why represent the metrics in a manner that is not consistent with how the code is being structured? Typically the reason I see given is "we don't want to change the POM file" a weak argument in my opinion.

Comment: The code is structured into modules that comprise a project.  Wanting to see code duplication across modules is the reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I can tell, and contrary to some [other forum posts](http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/Problem-with-setting-sonar-projectKey-for-maven-scan-td5014180.html), with at least v3.2 of the maven-sonar-plugin (maybe earlier) the `sonar.projectKey` property is respected and overrides the default of `${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}`.

Checking the source code also confirms it first looks for the property before defaulting it.

**org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.MavenSonarRunner.java**

```
private static void defineProjectKey(MavenProject pom, Properties props) {
  String key;
  if (pom.getModel().getProperties().containsKey(ScanProperties.PROJECT_KEY)) {
    key = pom.getModel().getProperties().getProperty(ScanProperties.PROJECT_KEY);
  } else {
    key = getSonarKey(pom);
  }
  props.setProperty(MODULE_KEY, key);
}

private static String getSonarKey(MavenProject pom) {
  return new StringBuilder().append(pom.getGroupId()).append(":").append(pom.getArtifactId()).toString();
}
```

**org.sonarsource.scanner.api.ScanProperties**

```
String PROJECT_KEY = "sonar.projectKey";
```

So by setting the following in the POM, for example, the projectKey can be overriden:

```
<properties>
    <sonar.projectKey>myprefix:${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</sonar.projectKey>
</properties>
```

Tested on Maven 3.3.9. In case this helps anyone!

Link to original GitHub Source:
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-maven/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/bootstrap/MavenProjectConverter.java

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup and use a multi modules / aggregator project for that http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation.

Just pass the aggregator pom that contains the modules to the sonar build and it should group all modules together. The grouping name is taken from the aggregator artifact-property (and can be overwritten by its name-property).

```
<groupId>...</groupId>
<artifactId>aggregator-project</artifactId>
<version>...</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Group name overrites artifactId</name>

<modules>
 <module>my-project</module>
 <module>another-project</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: This of course breaks when deploying to a repository - since funky groupId and artifactId are used for the deployment.